# How can I implement "UDP hole punching" in my IoT project?

Tags: node.js, web-services, networking, web, raspberry-pi

I have my Raspberry Pi at home running a webpage with Node.JS, with no UPnP or Port Forwarding thing.

Is there a way to implement "UDP hole punching" in my IoT project?

I planning to create a IoT project that just works "Out of the Box"... I thought that creating a VPN could be a solution. What do you guys think?

Thanks cool people.

Comment: Have you read about how UDP hole punching works as described [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/udp-hole-punching/)?  What you you tried in implementing that?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your comment! ok first of all I started to use Node.JS a couple of months ago when I bought my first Raspberry Pi, when I was looking for a solution to accessing it from internet, I red about UPnP and I couldn't understand it, same with UDP Hole Punching, my problem is not knowing how to implement it with a programming language, in my case Node.JS. But by now, I have a webpage running good, controlling all de GPIO ports. Did I explain myself? sorry about my english.

Comment: UDP hole punching requires another server out on the internet that both sides can initially contact. You would need that.  For just setting up your own project, I'd suggest you just use port forwarding in your router for an incoming http request.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your help and advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make my comments into an answer...

UDP hole punching usually requires another server out on the internet that both sides can initially contact to communicate public IP addresses. You would need that outside server which I assume you are not planning on having.   This would be more common for a service which you were going to offer to many users, not for a personal project.

For just setting up your own project, I'd suggest you just use port forwarding in your router for an incoming http request.

FYI, there's a pretty good description of the UDP hole punching here: [Circumventing NAT with UDP hole punching](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/udp-hole-punching/).

And, here's a node.js server implementation for hole punching: https://github.com/jankolkmeier/node-upd-hole-punching

Comment: I'm starting with a at-home project, but I have the possibility to have an outside server as you said.

Comment: @enKoding - Then probably worth initially setting up with port forwarding and then if you decide you want to make it general purpose for others, you can set up a public server to facilitate UDP hole punching.  Yes, the images are broken in the article, but the text is very well written.

Comment: I'm trying another easy-to-use tool called "Port Mapper" written in Java. Pretty cool anyways.